# How to retain indexPath value through multiple detail view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

How can I retain the indexPath value from my RootViewController through my multiple detail view controllers?

I have a split view controller and multiple detail views with a toolbar.

I want to be able to change the detailview upon calling a method which retrieves the indexPath.row value and uses indexPath.row+1.

So basically, I want each view controller to have a selectedRow = indexPath assignment. Currently I am getting an indexPath not declared for use error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to manage this.

Every time the selection changes, each of the detail view controllers can write their selection state to some common location.
Whenever on gets a viewWillAppear: it sets its selection.

or

If you're using a segmented view controller, in the action it is invoking, it can take the selection from the current detail view controller, change the controllers, and set the selection in the new controller.

or … *ad infinitum*

---

Familiarize yourself with the documentation of [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - `indexPathForSelectedRow` is how you'll grab the selected index, and `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` is how you set it on a table.  Be warned that sending an invalid indexPath will cause an exception.  If the tables are not the same size this could be a problem.  wrap with a `@try` or check before calling

Comment: How do I get each detailViewController's indexPath?

Comment: `indexPathForSelectedRow` - details added above